# How to rename rows with pattern in chunk using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame (tibble):

```
library(tidyverse)
lines<-"
A,foo,9394981
B,bar,6826405
C,qux,1074885
D,gop,1493691   
A,foo,100
B,bar,200
C,qux,300
D,gop,400 
"
con <- textConnection(lines)
dat <- read.csv(con,header=FALSE)
close(con)
dat <- as.tibble(dat)
dat
```

The values in `V2` comes in the chunk of four, i.e. always in `foo, bar, qux, gop`:

```
> dat
# A tibble: 8 × 3
      V1     V2      V3
  <fctr> <fctr>   <dbl>
1      A    foo 9394981
2      B    bar 6826405
3      C    qux 1074885
4      D    gop 1493691
5      A    foo     100
6      B    bar     200
7      C    qux     300
8      D    gop     400
```

How can I rename the row in `V2` so that it becomes like this:

```
  A    foo.w 9394981
  B    bar.x 6826405
  C    qux.y 1074885
  D    gop.z 1493691
  A    foo.w     100
  B    bar.x     200
  C    qux.y     300
  D    gop.z     400
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# If V2 is in the order of foo, bar, qux, gop
dat %>% mutate(V2=paste(V2, c("w", "x", "y", "z"), sep="."))
# A tibble: 8 × 3
      V1    V2      V3
  <fctr> <chr>   <dbl>
1      A foo.w 9394981
2      B bar.x 6826405
3      C qux.y 1074885
4      D gop.z 1493691
5      A foo.w     100
6      B bar.x     200
7      C qux.y     300
8      D gop.z     400

# If not, create a lookup
lookup <- c("foo"="foo.w", "bar"="bar.x", "qux"="qux.y", "gop"="gop.z")
dat %>% mutate(V2=lookup[as.character(V2)])
# A tibble: 8 × 3
      V1    V2      V3
  <fctr> <chr>   <dbl>
1      A foo.w 9394981
2      B bar.x 6826405
3      C qux.y 1074885
4      D gop.z 1493691
5      A foo.w     100
6      B bar.x     200
7      C qux.y     300
8      D gop.z     400
```